# Error while building a ggplot2 extension. Could not find function ggproto

Tags: r, ggplot2, build, package, rstudio

I try to build a custom geom to extend ggplot2.

While the function works, I am not able to build the package as I have the following error message:

```
    ==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

    Updating ggvis documentation
Loading ggvis
    Error in ggproto("GeomDash", Geom, required_aes = c("x", "y"), non_missing_aes = c("linetype",  (from geom_dash.R#57) : 
impossible de trouver la fonction "ggproto"
    Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... withr_with_dir -> force -> source_many -> source_one -> eval -> eval
Ex�cution arr�t�e

Exited with status 1.
```

I installed the dev version of ggplot2 as [recommanded by Hadley](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/40Qd5d_OTpg). With no success. For some reason it does not show an error when I try with a dummy function such as:

```
    f <- function(x){
        return(ggproto(x))}
```

But it doesn't work even with the initial code of geom_segment or by integrating the ggproto function in the package's folder.

You can find my function [here](https://github.com/Clement-Viguier/ggvis/blob/master/R/geom_dash.R)

I've already created a [package to extend ggplot2](https://github.com/Clement-Viguier/ShadeR) with no problem. It still builds just fine.

Any suggestion? Cheers.

Comment: You need to update you NAMESPACE file (or have Roxygen update it for you). If you look at the NAMESPACE of your problem package, it only has a single line, and it's an `export` line--no namespaces are imported. Compare this to the NAMESPACE of your working package, which has lines to `import()` each of the packages mentioned as `Imports` in your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: I fill have a look. Isn't Roxygen supposed to create the NAMESPACE file according to the DESCRIPTION file ?

Comment: Especially if the geom_function contains the following lines:
        `#' @import ggplot2 grid
        #' @importFrom ggplot2 ggproto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by editing the NAMESPACE as suggested by @Gregor.

Removing the existing NAMESPACE file and running

```
    devtools::document()
```

allowed the creation of a clean NAMESPACE file containing the required exports and imports.